# Two Select in a Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to make two values of a value from a table, and any value that has been selected will fall into a separate variable.

For example:

```
SELECT        id,username
FROM            New_Table
WHERE        (MONTH(date_en) = 01) AS month1 
WHERE        (MONTH(date_en) = 02) AS month2
```

I want this Select to be done `(MONTH (date_en) = 01) AS month1` and this `(MONTH (date_en) = 02) AS month2` will be selected separately in a Query

How can i do it ???

Comment: if I understood correctly your request you need "UNION ALL"

Comment: The WHERE clause decides if a row is returned or not. You can do `WHERE MONTH(date_en) in (01, 02)`.

Comment: May you reformulate it clearly so it doesnt looks like you don't know about the `AND` key word and you are not trying to have 2 times the `WHERE`

Comment: So you want to select `id`, `username` and a third value that holds `month1` or `month2` depending on the `date_en` value?

Comment: I read this as he wants to 'pivot' his months to columns and end up with 4 columns, `id`,`username`,`month1`,`month2`

Comment: @Bijan Rafraf, I think you're right.

Comment: I need to select two diffrents Value , So I can not use "And" or "OR"

Comment: I need to Select all the records that are in the second(February) and third(March) months @BijanRafraf

Comment: You need to clarify what you are looking for. Do you want two columns in a table? or do you want two tables? or do you simply want two numbers, a count of records for February and a count for March? or maybe a sum for Feb and a sum for March? Saying "Two Variables" is quite ambiguous.

Comment: Alex has given you the answer to the "One table with a column for each month" question. Larnu has given you the answer to "One table which has only records from certain months"

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for a next solution:

```
select
    id,
    username,
    CASE WHEN MONTH(date_en) = 01 THEN MONTH(date_en) ELSE '' END as month1,
    CASE WHEN MONTH(date_en) = 02 THEN MONTH(date_en) ELSE '' END as month2
from New_Table
```

As a result you would have line with filled-in month1 or month2 depend on month.

Double `WHERE` in your example is wrong syntax. If in some case you will need to check few conditions - learn about using keyword `OR`:

```
WHERE id = 1 OR id = 2
```

keyword `AND`:

```
WHERE id = 1 AND username = 'user1'
```

or keyword `IN`:

```
WHERE id IN (1, 2)
```

Comment: I tested that you said.
But all my data was selected and  "Where" did not work
You can see the photo in this link :https://www.dropbox.com/s/febkznldj4e7cwm/afdsfsdf.JPG?dl=0

Comment: @M. ZF, I check you link and query do what it suppose to. All your dates are in march - 3rd month, so it filled column with number 3. But, probably you expect something different. Could you please share your expectations with us? Please, enplane or draw the output you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you for you attention , I need to Select all the records that are in the second(February) and third(March) months

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/y9scvgshqcrmrwn/ddsfdsfdsf.JPG?dl=0  See this @Alex

Comment: Query for what you're are asking looks very simple: `SELECT id, username FROM New_Table where MONTH(date_en) = 01 OR MONTH(date_en) = 02` - take all rows where month is 2(Feb) or 3(Mar). Are you looking for it?

Comment: I want these two selections to be displayed in separate variables, not a field for example : (Feb) AS February , (Mar) AS March

Comment: @ M. ZF, query always return you a table, with rows and columns. It doesn't return you variables. I see what data you have under your links. What I don't get - what output you want to achieve. Please, take  second and draw or type how your output table should looks like and share with us.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, if you have multiple Criteria that **ALL** need to be fulfiled, then you can use `AND`. For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE Column1 = 1
  AND Column2 = 'A';
```

This means that both requirements needs to be met (`Column1` must have a value of `1`, and Column2 must have a value of `'A'`).

If only one of the requirements need to be met, you can use `OR`. For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE Column1 = 1
  AND Column1 = 2;
```

This means that rows where `Column1` has a value of `1` or `2` will be returned. As, also, these expressions reference the same column, the query can be shorted using the `IN` operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE Column1 IN (1,2);
```

There are many more operators in SQL than that, but if you aren't aware of these, I think you need to look at doing some training/learning first; as it seems you are very new to the language.

Comment: Another downvote, and no comment... Criticism is welcome, provided you're constructive.